# Object Detection using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

[fig:Shoe in the red circle is to be detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVh5O.png)
I am trying to create a python script using cv2 that can recognize the shoe of the baller and determine whether the shoe is beyond, on or before the white line(refer to the image).
I have no idea about any kind of approach to use, what kind of algorithms might be helpful. Need some guideline, please help!
(Image is attached)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this would work better as a comment because it isn't a full answer, but I don't have enough rep yet to leave comments, haha.

You may be interested in OpenCV's Canny Edge detection algorithm:
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html
This will allow you to find shapes within your image.

Also, you can find similarly colored blobs using SimpleBlobDetector:
https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/

This should make it fairly easy to detect the white line.

In order to detect a more complex object like the shoe, you'll probably have to make something like a object detection cascade file and use a CascadeClassifier to find it:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier

http://johnallen.github.io/opencv-object-detection-tutorial/

Basically, you take a bunch of pictures to "teach" what the object looks like, and output that info to a file that a CascadeClassifier can use to detect objects in input images. It may be hard to distinguish between different brands of shoe though, if you need it to be that specific. Also, you may need to adjust the input images (saturation, brightness, etc) before trying to detect objects in order to get good results.